# Is this a Fourier transformation?

Tags: fourier-analysis

As working on a crystallographic project, I saw somebody claimed that they can implement FFT on the following formula:
$$F(q)=\sum_rf(r,q)\exp(iqr)$$
How could they do FFT if $f$ is function of both $r$ and $q$?

Comment: That's bogus for a lot of reasons, not the least of which is that the number of variables of the transform and the original function have to match up always.